# Sending an email to a potential scammer

Tags: email

I own a website. Someone recently sent some questionable emails through our site to some other members. I wanted to send him an explanation of what our site is for and a warning not to send such messages again.

While these emails are not 100% malicious, I am a little hesitant to send him any email from our normal email account as I do not want our company email address falling into the wrong hands (getting spammed or other bad things).

Is is safe to send this user the warning through our company email or should I do something else to warn him? If so, how can I send him an email without jeopardizing our email account?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally, I'd never reply to SPAM / Phishing campaigns. Especially not from a domain you care about -for a few reasons:

- Responding lets the attacker know your email address is **live**
- He/She could respond by increasing the amount of SPAM sent your way.. or worse
- SPAMmers have little respect for law and "please stop" messages.

Basically, your email will either fall on deaf ears and nothing will happen, OR, they'll respond in a way you won't like.

**Recommendation**

I'd just add them to the SPAM filtering and move on. You can also report them to your ISP and let them handle it. This takes the burden/risk off of you acting by yourself.

Comment: I second hallowprocs answer.  Spammers don't give a damn about you, this has already been proven by the fact that you were targeted by them.  If anything you are just giving them more ammo to shoot back at you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My website actually has an email "server". ie: its users message each other via the website (message goes to site server, then to final destination). I am going to post another question on how I can stop spammers. Basically, the idea of reporting him isn't as straight forward in this scenario. Thanks.

Comment: This is the follow up question: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134302/stopping-spammers-from-using-my-websites-messaging